# How To Restrict Delete using PL/pgSQL trigger?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-9.6

If the client user is trying to delete more than 5 records from a Table i want to restrict that using a trigger. I have a basic idea to do that but i don't know how to implement the Idea. I appreciate any HELP.

Basic Idea : In Trigger IF TG_OP = Delete and the count of records to be deleted are more than 5 then Restrict.

```
CREATE TRIGGER adjust_count_trigger BEFORE DELETE ON schemaname.tablename
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.adjust_count();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION adjust_count()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
    DECLARE
        num_rows int;
        num_rows1 int;

    BEGIN

        IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN

            EXECUTE 'select count(*) from '||TG_TABLE_SCHEMA ||'.'||TG_RELNAME ||' where oid = old.oid ' into num_rows  ;


            IF num_rows > 5   Then

            RAISE NOTICE 'Cannot Delete More than 5 Records , % ', num_rows ;

            END IF ;


        END IF ;

        RETURN OLD;
    END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: dear  a_horse_with_no_name , Please suggest me a solution as i am not aware of it.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? In Postgres 10 you could do this with a statement level trigger that checks the transition table.

Comment: Even after deleting the line ,the issue is not fixed. @IMSoP

Comment: postgres 9.6 @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In earlier versions of Postgres you can simulate a transition table introduced in Postgres 10. You need two triggers.

```
create trigger before_delete 
before delete on my_table
for each row execute procedure before_delete();

create trigger after_delete 
after delete on my_table
for each statement execute procedure after_delete();
```

In the first trigger create a temp table and insert a row into it:

```
create or replace function before_delete()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    create temp table if not exists deleted_rows_of_my_table (dummy int);
    insert into deleted_rows_of_my_table values (1);
    return old;
end $$;
```

In the other trigger count rows of the temp table and drop it:

```
create or replace function after_delete()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
declare
    num_rows bigint;
begin
    select count(*) from deleted_rows_of_my_table into num_rows;
    drop table deleted_rows_of_my_table;
    if num_rows > 5 then
        raise exception 'Cannot Delete More than 5 Records , % ', num_rows;
    end if;
    return null;
end $$;
```

The above solution may seem a bit hacky but it is safe if only the temp table does not exist before delete (do not use the same name of the temp table for multiple tables).

[Test it in rextester.](http://rextester.com/DUU47508)

Comment: Thank you very very much..... My problem got solved and this worked. Am so grateful to you @klin

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that with the new transition relation feature from PostgreSQL v10:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION forbid_more_than() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   n bigint := TG_ARGV[0];
BEGIN
   IF (SELECT count(*) FROM deleted_rows) <= n IS NOT TRUE
   THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'More than % rows deleted', n;
   END IF;
   RETURN OLD;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER forbid_more_than_5
   AFTER DELETE ON mytable
   REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS deleted_rows
   FOR EACH STATEMENT
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE forbid_more_than(5);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But here the version is 9.6 and it is a live server ,So how to implement the same in PostgreSQL v9.6 ?

Comment: You cannot have this in PostgreSQL 9.6 and earlier.

Comment: @DeepanKaviarasu: if that feature is so important, then you should really consider upgrading