# Trigger that will build one row from several rows

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I mean:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, 'message'), (2, 'message'), (3, 'message);
```

triggering will cause the result in the table to look like this:

```
1, E'message\nmessage\nmessage'
```

How to forbid inserting rows and then continue operations on the transferred data in the insert?
I am using postresgql.

Comment: Should we assume the 3 combined 'message' strings are the combined values of the 3 rows from the INSERT statement?

Comment: Yes, exactly this I mean.

Comment: You can create on statement trigger that selects inserted rows and changes them to the format you desired and then deletes old records from the table.

Comment: I think that this cannot be done. I also don't understand the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres 10+ you can use a transition table in an AFTER trigger, see [Example 43.7. Auditing with Transition Tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-trigger.html). Assuming that `id` is a primary key (or unique):

```
create table my_table(id int primary key, message text);
```

you can update one and delete the remaining inserted rows:

```
create or replace function after_insert_on_my_table()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
declare r record;
begin
    select 
        array_agg(id) as ids, 
        array_to_string(array_agg(message), e'\n') as message
    from new_table
    into r;

    update my_table
    set message = r.message
    where id = r.ids[1];

    delete from my_table
    where id = any(r.ids[2:]);

    return null;
end $$;
```

In a trigger definition declare a transition table (as `new_table`):

```
create trigger after_insert_on_my_table
after insert on my_table
referencing new table as new_table
for each statement 
execute procedure after_insert_on_my_table();
```

In earlier versions of Postgres you can [simulate a transition table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48562537/1995738) introduced in Postgres 10.

[Test it in db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a22acd951f1f0af3b6a7e6e6b9532827)